# How to store array value and add another value php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write the product name and quantity from a given order, then read from the next order and add to the array but the final array only stores the value from the last loope
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I also tried array_push
I would like to count the number of units sold and display as follows for all orders:
Product A - 50 pieces
Product B - 30 pieces, etc.

```
        foreach ($order_id as $order_ids) {
            //echo '</br>' . $vendor_id . ' ' . $vendor_mail . ' ' . $vendor_name . '</br>';

            $orderID = $order_ids->order_id;
            $order_date = $order_ids->date_created;
            $single_order = wc_get_order($orderID);
            echo '</br>';
            echo __('ID zamówienia: ') . $orderID . '<br>';
            echo __('Data zamówienia: ') . $order_date . '<br>';

            $product_quantity = array();
            $product_name = array();
            $single_order_array=array();
            $array_merge=array();
            foreach ($single_order->get_items() as $item) {


                echo __('Nazwa produktu: ') . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
                echo __('Ilość: ') . $item->get_quantity() . '<br><br><br>';

                $product_quantity[] = $item->get_quantity();
                $product_name[] = $item->get_name();

                $single_order_array=array_combine($product_name, $product_quantity);


            }

            echo '</br>TABLICA POJEDYNCZEGO ZAMOWIENIA: </br>';
            print_r($single_order_array);
            echo '</br></br>';

            $array_merge=array_replace_recursive($single_order_array, $array_merge);



        }
        echo '</br>TABLICA CAŁEGO WENDORA : </br>';
        print_r($array_merge);
        echo '</br></br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer**

According to your code `$single_order_array` will be overwritten within each loop of `foreach ($single_order->get_items() as $item)`. So in this array you will get data only for last item from order.
As for usage of `array_replace_recursive` I can't quite get your idea. BTW how do you get you initial array `$order_id`?

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```php
$results=array(); // place this outside all loops
foreach ($order_id as $order_ids) {
            //echo '</br>' . $vendor_id . ' ' . $vendor_mail . ' ' . $vendor_name . '</br>';

            $orderID = $order_ids->order_id;
            $order_date = $order_ids->date_created;
            $single_order = wc_get_order($orderID);
            echo '</br>';
            echo __('ID zamówienia: ') . $orderID . '<br>';
            echo __('Data zamówienia: ') . $order_date . '<br>';

            $product_quantity = array();
            $product_name = array();
            $single_order_array=array();
            foreach ($single_order->get_items() as $item) {

                echo __('Nazwa produktu: ') . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
                echo __('Ilość: ') . $item->get_quantity() . '<br><br><br>';
                $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();
                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                $single_order_array[]=array($product_name => $product_quantity);
            }

            echo '</br>TABLICA POJEDYNCZEGO ZAMOWIENIA: </br>';
            print_r($single_order_array);
            echo '</br></br>';

            foreach ($single_order_array as $product=>$quantity){
                if (array_key_exists($product, $results)){
                $results[$product]+=$quantity;}
                else {$results += array ($product=>$quantity);
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</br>TABLICA CAŁEGO WENDORA : </br>';
        print_r($results);
        echo '</br></br>';
```

Sould work but not tested as I have no idea how orders' data is stored into your input array `$order_id`.

Comment: That is why my question is how to store the data from the previous loop and add it to the new one each time.
orderid I have a sql query which I did not paste here 
I would like to save the product name and quantity from all orders
I use the yith vendor plugin and I make a summary report for each seller

Comment: So the answer is as suggested below - use `$single_order_array[]=array_combine($product_name, $product_quantity);`
instead of
`$single_order_array=array_combine($product_name, $product_quantity);`

As for `$array_merge=array_replace_recursive($single_order_array, $array_merge);` I still don't get what's the idea here

Comment: You'd better provide an example array, otherwise it's too difficult to judge without knowing array structure.

Comment: @ncti, I tried to fix your code, check the result in the answer

Comment: @ncti, what's the purpose of asking questions here and not bothering to check the answer?

Comment: sorry i haven't been at the computer since friday

Comment: The idea is that he wants to make a summary of sales of all products from all orders, e.g.
there were 20 breads in all orders,
rolls were 50
now I have separate orders and I would like to merge it.

Comment: The array still returns the value of the last order
This is my full code https://paste.in/ZvODp9

Comment: @ncti, the code should work. In your full code it seems like you commented our final `print_r`, so the final results are not printed. If that's not the issue than I can only propose you to provide input array for testing, otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: I have uncommented and last results for $results is the same what in case when I print $single_order_array :/

Comment: @ncti, looks like results are zeroed in every loop due to `$results=array();` being inside foreach loop. Try moving it outside all loops, e.g. somewhere in the very beginning of code.

Comment: You mean last foreach?

Comment: @ncti, I edited original code to reflect this. Just move this line of code
`$results=array();` outside of of any `foreach` loop and place it somewhere in the beginning of snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is updating the values. You need to use associative array and store values in it. This will solve your problem.

```
$data = [];

for($i =0; $i<sizeof($items); $i++) 
{

$data[$i]['item_value_1'] = $items[$i]->item_value_1;
$data[$i]['item_value_2'] = $items[$i]->item_value_2;
$data[$i]['item_value_3'] = $items[$i]->item_value_3;

}
```